# How to change the animation of the dropdown menu in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animate.css

I use bootstrap and animate.css in my website skin. Is this possible that I change effect of appear submenu in bootstrap menu with animate.css?

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean changing the animation of the dropdown menu?

Comment: The answer to your question is quite simple, 138200. **Yes, it is possible**.

Comment: It depends on the expected outcome. Do you think we know what you want if you don't tell us? You can read about TB events [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events).

Comment: What kind of animation do you want? Do you want an animation once the menu has dropped down or do you want an animation on dropdown etc.?

Comment: Evochrome  : For example, the slide down animation and I want an animation on dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think this will fullfill your needs:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/53j9x0Ln/5/)

CODE (JS):

```
$('.dropdown-menu').addClass('invisible'); //FIRST TIME INVISIBLE

// ADD SLIDEDOWN ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN-MENU 
  $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('invisible');
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
  });

  // ADD SLIDEUP ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN-MENU 
  $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
  });
```

Instead of adding the javascript above, you can also try adding this CSS code:

[DEMO_2](https://jsfiddle.net/53j9x0Ln/6/)

CODE (CSS):

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    height: 0px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
-moz-transition: height 1s ease;
-ms-transition: height 1s ease;
-o-transition: height 1s ease;
transition: height 1s ease;

}


.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    height:200px;
    opacity: 1;

}
```

Cheers,

**EDIT:** I found that using `all` instead of `height` is even smooth as it also animates the opacity.

Comment: Thanks a lot . This is a powerful  answer         :-)

Answer (score 2):

No need to use slides or other workarounds Here is a simple Solution :

1. Add **animate.css** to your project(google it everyone knows it)
2. Add **animated** class to your dropdown-menu
3. Use the following piece of Js:(show() is very important)

   ```
   $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
       $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('lightSpeedOut').addClass('lightSpeedIn').show();
   });

   $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
       $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('lightSpeedIn').addClass('lightSpeedOut');
   });
   ```

   **Tested with Bootstrap 4.3.1(Currently Latest) Should also works with Bootstrap 3.x**

Comment: Works in BS 5 too. Thanks loads!

Comment: The classes of animate css are changed from previous versions so make sure everyone looks at the proper documentation at https://animate.style/